# Visitor pattern Java and global variables

Tags: java, global-variables, jsoup, visitor-pattern

I'm using JSoup and I'm doing some node traversal.

```
String myString;
NodeTraversor articleNodeTraversor  = new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {

            @Override
            public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
                //Do some processing.
                                    myString += "foo";
            }

            @Override
            public void head(Node node, int depth) { 
                //Do some processing.
            }
        });
```

Firstly, what is this kind of programming called? Visitor pattern? Secondly, the above code only works if myString is global. How can I make my string local to only the method it is being created in and still make the above work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using anonymous classes, so they can access only final local variables outside of its context ( assuming its declared within a method )and any variable of the class ( static or non-static). Also you can declare variables within the inner class, BUT static non-final variable declarations are not allowed.

Comment: Are you saying that I have to make myString global if I want to be able to modify it inside the inner class and in the method in which myString is declared?

Comment: not sure what you mean by global, since this is OO. But you can declare the string variable within the inner class code like this `
NodeTraversor articleNodeTraversor  = new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {
            String myString;
            @Override
            public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
                //Do some processing.
                                    myString += "foo";
            }

            @Override
            public void head(Node node, int depth) { 
                //Do some processing.
            }
        });`

Comment: I ened up making it not anonymous so that I could then access the variable from the method that the inner class was declared in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The block `new NodeVisitor() {}` was called Anonymous Inter Class.

You can treat your variables in the block as common class.